# vffiddle is available

Tags: discussion

I was fortunate to see a live demonstration of [vffiddle](http://vffiddle.herokuapp.com/) at Dreamforce by it's creator, [Nate Lipke](https://twitter.com/EvilN8) (thank you!).  It is based off of [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), but works with Visualforce.

This is an excellent way for users to post workable code snippets on SFSE.  When posting, try to keep the features being used in the code common to those in all orgs (e.g., Accounts, Contacts, etc.) to make it more likely that the code will run in anyone's org that runs the fiddle.

[image: vffiddle screen capture]

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with  vffiddle, or the link is throwing out an error Error: Lexical error on line 76. Unrecognized text. ...} . I thought i would use it for demonstrating to a colleague of mine  :) . This certainly would be very helpful specially in SFSE

Comment: Can this be used with a sandbox?  It seems to want to log in to production.

Comment: @Jagular - Nate tweeted at me that he is working on it. See here: https://twitter.com/EvilN8/status/524377242323808256

Comment: are there any security concerns to adding this to a production org?  Any more info on what is actually going on behind the scenes?  Unfortunately I missed the demo at Dreamforce (8:30am was a bit too early for me).  Seems like a sweet tool

Comment: @NSjonas - It looks like it uses oauth and runs as a connected app. It is not advisable to run directly in production. For code samples, it would be a production deployment (run all unit tests, etc.).  Technically, I think the only possibility, besides some failure of the connected app framework, would be executing code that does something harmful (e.g., delete, truncate, etc.).

Comment: Since you posted this, thought you might want to know that the following post [Should I add sandbox support to vfiddle?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53856/should-i-add-sandbox-support-to-vffiddle) was put on hold 2 days ago. @NateLipke was looking for beta testers as part of that post. I believe he's asked for his post to be moved to Meta.

Comment: I'll use this post to notify people when it's available for testing. Unless, you think it would be better as a separate post.

Comment: Sure. That's fine to use this post.

Comment: Very cool.  I notice I don't even have to log in, and i'm apparently already logged in.  What org does this work against?  Is it one of my orgs or is there a vffiddle org?  If I share the fiddle with someone else does it deploy all the code to the org its viewed in?

Comment: @PhilRymek - It uses the org that you are authenticated with. It prompted me as a connected app.  When someone runs your fiddle they are deploying/creating your code to their sandbox; hence the need to try to avoid obscure custom objects, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I finally added sandbox support (sorry for the delay).

Also, I added support for:

- React
- Underscore
- AngularJS

Testing appreciated.

Comment: Great job, thank you!

Comment: Any plans to make it clean up after itself?

Comment: It's on the list,  not sure when though. Do you have any specific thoughts on how to clean it up? Just delete the class and page or something cleaner?